# RabbitMQ: Connection Refused

Tags: ruby, connection, rabbitmq, port

I am trying to run the basic ruby tutorial after installing it through both:

```
gem install bunny --version ">= 2.5.1"
```

and

```
brew install rabbitmq
```

then running the sender.rb file.

Then I get this error:

```
W, [2016-11-16T19:17:28.891581 #96531]  WARN -- #<Bunny::Session:0x7ff56e055120 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>: Could not establish TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5672: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:5672
/Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bunny-2.6.1/lib/bunny/session.rb:322:in `rescue in start': Could not establish TCP connection to any of the configured hosts (Bunny::TCPConnectionFailedForAllHosts)
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bunny-2.6.1/lib/bunny/session.rb:288:in `start'
    from sender.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Is RabbitMQ running? Is it listening on `127.0.0.1:5672`?

Comment: brew services start rabbitmq